# SMD Device and manufacturer ID markings S2

Tags: identification, surface-mount, device

I have a SMD device that I am am trying to identify. [image: S2 device]

Can anyone point me to a manufacturer? Probably a resistor but I am not sure.
Any help would be appreciated.

The scale bar in the picture is not correct

Comment: Looks like a diode to me

Comment: Can you get a DMM on diode mode on that thing?

Comment: There are some varactor diodes in a similar looking package & marking. What's the function of the circuit?

Comment: The circuit board is an LCD driver board. I always thought diodes had a polarity mark of some sort; I'll probe and do some tests.

Comment: I suspect that vague dotted stripe on the left is intended to be the polarity marking...

Answer (score 1):

Taiwan Semiconductor makes a [1N4448](https://www.taiwansemi.com/products/datasheet/1N4148WS%20SERIES_L1804.pdf) diode in a SOD-323F package with 'S2' marking.
Some accurate measurements on the package would help to confirm.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[https://www.amazon.com/huaban-CMS02-Marking-Schottky-Barrier/dp/B01MEHIITR](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MEHIITR)

Thanks to all that responded it appears to be a huaban CMS02 M-FLAT Marking S2 Schottky Barrier Diode